# How to completely remove steam?

Tags: steam

I downloaded steam via terminal and it worked but without full features. Later I tried to download it from the steam site and it replaced the other version, but when I tried to open it, it didn't work. I tried deleting it, then I tried downloading the windows version (from their site) using Wine and that didn't work either, so I tried to delete it all and just get the first version I had back and I was only able to delete some files and when I try to download it, it can't overwrite the other files or something so now I have all these (see picture), I can't delete them, and I have no access to steam.

[image: Annoying steam files picture]

How can I remove all this?

Comment: What do you mean you can't delete them? You don't have permission?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Yes I'm the one who asked the question I'm putting this here in-case someone else had problems) You can delete some of them through the terminal with

sudo rm /path/to/file

If its a folder you need to use

sudo rmdir /path/to/folder

For the ones That can't be removed by sudo in terminal you need to access the root command line to do so you must:

Logging out, press Ctrl+Alt+F1, it will say "(ComputerName) login:" type "root" press enter, it will ask for your password, type your password, press enter again, if your login was successful, congratulations you are now in the full out CLI (Command Line Interface) if not try again.

From there you must be careful what you as you will not need to type sudo to do anything you can very easily delete a file that is required for running your computer once you understand this:

you simply do almost the same thing as before but you no longer need sudo.

rm /path/to/file

or if its a folder

rmdir /path/to/folder

Note: when typing the /path/to/file and /path/to/folder
                      ^                 ^
it is important to put a "/" before the path to file/folder  as you be in the directory "/root" visualized by "(computername)@root:~$" the "~" signifying the home directory (for root)

Other note: you can find the path to the file or folder by finding it in Files, left-clicking on it once, right-clicking, clicking properties (at bottom of the right-click pop-up thing and there you find its name and path along with other information that might help you with problems in future (for other apps/files/folders of course)